# Add list with categories to choose from and save it as the category for the post

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I have a solution for the fact that users can now add categories to their posts. Problem: they don't know which already exist and which do. Therefore, I'd like to go to a route where users can choose (checkbox?) the categories that exist.

My question: how to do this properly?

My code is as follows:

```
                           if(isset($_POST['entry']) AND !$_POST['entry'] == ""):
$my_post = array();

$my_post['post_title']   = $_POST['title'];
$my_post['post_content'] = $_POST['entry'];
$my_post['post_status']  = 'publish';

$cat_name             = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['newcat'] );
$my_post ['cat_name'] = $cat_name;

$category_id = get_cat_ID( $_POST['newcat'] );

if ( ! $category_id ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        die();
    }
$args = array(
    'description' => "Category description",
    'parent' => 0);
    $category_id = wp_insert_term( $_POST['newcat'], "category", $args );
}

$my_post['post_author'] = get_current_user_id();

$my_post['tax_input'] = array('category' => $category_id);


wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

And then I am showing the dropdown categories, yet I can't save my choice when adding the checkboxes for categories.

```
$categories=get_categories();   foreach($categories as $category) {     echo "<input type='checkbox' name='mychecky' value='$category->term_id' />";    echo $category->cat_name;
    echo '<br>';    }
```

How can I save the chosen category per checklist for my post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form checklist should accept multiple values so it must be an array. Array in HTML forms has square brackets `[]` so your checkbox name should look like `mychecky[]`. The full code for checkbox inputs:

```
$categories = get_categories();
foreach($categories as $category) {
   echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='mychecky[]' value='$category->term_id' />$category->cat_name</label><br>";
}
```

Then when you check POST data you should expect an array from the form and you can assign it like it is since `post_category` parameter must be an array anyway:

```
// it is an array from a form with category IDs
if (isset($_REQUEST['mychecky'])) {
   $my_post['post_category'] = $_REQUEST['mychecky'];
}
```

You can use your methods with taxonomy or use built in `post_category`, check docs for [wp_inset_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) function.